# How to extract timestamp (Capturing time) for each frame from video (dvt or any files)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, timestamp, command, frame

I want to extract the timestamp (date and time which is associated with each frame while recording) for each frame from a video file. The file format may be .dvt .mp4 etc. Is there any ubuntu command or python code to extract timestamp associated with each frames?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to take a look at the format (.dvt or .mp4) standard. If the frames are accessible independently, you can most likely parse the meta data. Those meta data can be extracted according to the standard specification or by revserse engineering.

Comment: The short answer is, good luck. It's an incredible pain to find it in the metadata of many/most file formats, so much so that companies sell software packages for Gstreamer with the only functionality being to parse this information (See RidgeRun, etc.)